# How to retrieve the current user in Teams app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm new to teams development. How can I retrieve the full name of the user that is currently log on in the teams app. I'm a bit lost in the getContext that I saw in the documentation. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the userPrincipalName by using the getContext(). Use the Graph API to get the full name and other details of the user.

Follow these steps:

User need to perform Sign In to call Graph APIs

1. Get UPN Id from GetContext()
2. Use it as login hint while Sign In.
3. Call [Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) graph API to fetch display name.

Refer to Sample code and docs: [Authentication flow for tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab)